# Render a new row onPress() of button React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx

I want to add functionality eg: 'Add New Record'. I want whenever user clicked on 'Add New' button so new row should be generated below. after that I also want the data of every single row. My attached code is not working, I've also attached the error. Please provide me a solution or another trick for it. Thanks.

Error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.row.push')

```
    constructor(){
       super()
       this.state = {
          rows: []
       }
    }
    index = 0;
    _addRow(){
      this.state.rows.push(this.index++)
      this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows })
    }
    render(){
       let rows = this.state.rows.map((r, i) => {
        return <View key={ i } style={[styles.row, CheckIndex(i)]}>
                  <Text >Row { r }, Index { i }</Text>
               </View>
       })
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this._addRow } style={styles.button}>
                <Text>Add new row</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
            { rows }
          </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use something like

```
_addRow(){
  this.setState(prevState => ({ rows: [...prevState.rows, prevState.rows.length] }));
}
```

Instead of

```
 _addRow(){
      this.state.rows.push(this.index++)
      this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the code given below

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       rows: [],
       index:0
    }
}

_addRow = ()=>{
    this.state.rows.push(this.state.index+1)
    this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows, index :  this.state.index+1});
}
```